# Logging to different folders with Elmah

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, elmah, error-logging

We have a Webservice that has been logging `Elmah` errors as `XML` files into a folder. This webservice application has pure `ASMX` webservices and `ASPX` webservices.

We now have a requirement to log these errors to different folders based on whether the error is occurring in the pure `ASMX` webservices or the `ASPX` webservices. The `ASMX` webservices log errors using a `SoapExtension` whereas the `ASPX` webservices log errors using custom error logging.

**Is logging to different folders supported in Elmah?**

*Global.asax.cs*

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var xmlFileErrorLog = (XmlFileErrorLog)ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current);
            elmahLogPathField.SetValue(xmlFileErrorLog, elmahDirectory);
        }

protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (loggingEnabledDocumentManagement == "0")
            {
                e.Dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience and a review of the Elmah docs at [Elmah (code.google.com)](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) I do not believe this is possible with one instance of Elmah.  All the documentation talks about choosing the output location.

It seems the only solution is to wrap calls to Elmah with a method that redirects to two different Elmah loggers.